# Buy points with Gaming Evolved

Tags: raptr

I have about 10,000 points on the AMD Gaming Evolved app, and have my eye on the R9 270 graphics card which costs 80,000 points. Is there any way I can use my points to get a discount on the card, then pay the remainder with money? If not, can I buy reward points with real money?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the [Terms of Service](http://raptr.com/info/tos), it turns out that:

- No, you cannot use your points and pay the remainder with money, since

  > Rewards have no cash value.
- You cannot buy reward points with real money either, neither from Raptr, nor from other users:

  > The Service may offer points that can be earned by performing certain actions and tasks in and in association with the Service and Games (“Rewards”).
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > Points do not have any monetary value and cannot be transferred to other users or redeemed for money.